# How to get column which is assigned under another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

This is my GroupTable.

```
CREATE TABLE GroupTable(
  ID INT,
  GROUPNAME VARCHAR(50),
  UnderGroupId INT
);

INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (1,'A',0);
INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (2,'B',1);
INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (3,'C',2);
INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (4,'D',3);
```

Below is the datatable where i'm passing groupId in data table for reference

```
CREATE TABLE Reference(
  ID INT,
  GROUPID VARCHAR(50),
  GroupValue VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Reference VALUES (1,3,'X');
INSERT INTO Reference VALUES (2,4,'Y');
INSERT INTO Reference VALUES (3,1,'Z');
```

and i want to show the result like this

```
| ID | GROUPID | GroupValue | GROUPNAME1 | GROUPNAME2 | GROUPNAME3 | GROUPNAME4 |
|----|---------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|  1 |       3 |          X |          A |          B |          C |            |
|  2 |       4 |          Y |          A |          B |          C |          D |
|  3 |       1 |          Z |          A |            |            |            |
```

Comment: Waht's the logic from `GroupName1` to `GroupName4` colnums in your expect result?

Comment: they are just name of GroupName from GroupTable which is assigned under each another

Comment: But why there are three `A` in `GroupName1 `,two `B` in `GroupName2` in your expect result?

Comment: the second table is main table fot this, and the first table is reference table here. so now , when we take first value "3" from groupId, and id is linked to refernce table(1) , then 3's group name is C and C is undergroupid 2 , and 2's group name is B and B is under A in that table. 

thats why there i have written A three times in groupname1 (in 3rd table)
in other words
i am following the path from backward . like for value "3"is D so in group name 4 its written D , adn its upper is groupname is groupname3 where group id C is written because D is under C . and so on.. 
hope you get it.

Comment: I edit your question use format instead of the image because format data can help people easier do in sqlfiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you can try to `OUTER JOIN` by `GROUPID > UnderGroupId` condition because that condition is those two table relationship condition.

then

1. `UnderGroupId = 0` mean the group1
2. `UnderGroupId = 1` mean the group2
3. `UnderGroupId = 2` mean the group3
4. `UnderGroupId = 3` mean the group4

You can do  *condition aggregate function* on `UnderGroupId`, to get the pivot result.

**TestDLL**

```
CREATE TABLE GroupTable(
  ID INT,
  GROUPNAME VARCHAR(50),
  UnderGroupId INT
);

INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (1,'A',0);
INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (2,'B',1);
INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (3,'C',2);
INSERT INTO GroupTable VALUES (4,'D',3);

CREATE TABLE Reference(
  ID INT,
  GROUPID VARCHAR(50),
  GroupValue VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Reference VALUES (1,3,'X');
INSERT INTO Reference VALUES (2,4,'Y');
INSERT INTO Reference VALUES (3,1,'Z');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.GROUPID,  
       t1.GroupValue,
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN UnderGroupId = 0 THEN tt.GROUPNAME end),'') GROUPNAME1,
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN UnderGroupId = 1 THEN tt.GROUPNAME end),'') GROUPNAME2,
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN UnderGroupId = 2 THEN tt.GROUPNAME end),'') GROUPNAME3,
       coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN UnderGroupId = 3 THEN tt.GROUPNAME end),'') GROUPNAME4
FROM Reference t1 
LEFT JOIN GroupTable tt ON t1.GROUPID > tt.UnderGroupId
GROUP BY t1.ID,
       t1.GROUPID,  
       t1.GroupValue
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/067c9b1/14/0)**:

```
| ID | GROUPID | GroupValue | GROUPNAME1 | GROUPNAME2 | GROUPNAME3 | GROUPNAME4 |
|----|---------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|  1 |       3 |          X |          A |          B |          C |            |
|  2 |       4 |          Y |          A |          B |          C |          D |
|  3 |       1 |          Z |          A |            |            |            |
```

Comment: Thanks i got the result

Comment: @Roshan No problem glad to help :)

Comment: Hi @D-Shih
It would be more better if you can explain the query which you have written...

Comment: @HNK Ok I add some explain